# Derivative in cylindrical coordinates

Tags: coordinate-systems, differentiation, vector-fields

Why do we multiply a $\frac{1}{r}$ factor for the  gradient unit vector in $\vec{\theta}$ direction? and how is the angle a vector here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the components of the vector $\vec{R}$ given with polar coordinates are:

$$\vec{R}= \begin{bmatrix}
   x \\
   y \\
 \end{bmatrix}= r\,\begin{bmatrix}
   \cos(\varphi) \\
   \sin(\varphi) \\
 \end{bmatrix}=r\,\cos(\varphi)\hat{e}_x+r\,\sin(\varphi)\hat{e}_y$$

with :

$$\hat{\vec{e}_r}=\frac{1}{||\frac{\partial \vec{R}}{\partial r}||}\,\frac{\partial \vec{R}}{\partial r}=\begin{bmatrix}
   \cos(\varphi) \\
   \sin(\varphi) \\
 \end{bmatrix}$$

and

$$\hat{\vec{e}_\phi}=\frac{1}{||\frac{\partial \vec{R}}{\partial \varphi}||}\,\frac{\partial \vec{R}}{\partial \varphi}=\begin{bmatrix}
   -\sin(\varphi) \\
   \cos(\varphi) \\
 \end{bmatrix}$$

you can write the vector R in coordinates  $\quad \hat{\vec{e}_r}\,,\hat{\vec{e}_\phi}\quad$ system

$$\vec{R}=a_r\,\hat{\vec{e}_r}+a_\phi\,\hat{\vec{e}_\phi}$$

where $a_r=r$ and $a_\varphi=0$

The transformation matrix between those  two coordinate system is:

$$S=\left[\hat{\vec{e}_r}\,,\hat{\vec{e}_\phi}\right]$$

Answer (score 0):

1. we do it since it comes out this way, if yo transform from cartesian ti polar coordinates see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polar_coordinate_system
2. in the grad you alway have 1/length so you need the 1/r to get the right dimension of grad.
3. how will you describe motion in polar coordinates if the angle has no direction?

Answer (score 0):

The position vector (or the radius vector) is a vector R that represents the position of
points in the Euclidean space with respect to an arbitrarily selected point O, known
as the origin. We can parameterize this position vector as a function of coordinates and define basis vectors using it. In polar coordinates, it is a function of $r$ and $ \theta$, where $r$ is the radial distance from a chosen origin and $\theta$, is the angle which the radial distance from the arbitrarily chosen origin makes with a line.

We can derive the basis vector of this polar coordinate system by doing derivatives on this parameterized position vector. The partial derivative of this position vector with respect to $\theta$ gives the local basis in $\theta$ direction. The word local is used because unlike the cartesian coordinate system, the polar coordinate system has a natural basis that changes from point to point.

---

**Working out the angular polar basis vector:**

[image]

Consider taking the partial of $ R$ w.r.t $ \theta$ when the radial distance is some $r$ away, you get:

$$ \frac{ \partial R}{\partial \theta} =\vec{ e_{\theta}}$$

But if you did this at some other $r'$ distance away with $ r'>r$, your basis vector scales up by some factor. Most precisely, the basis evaluated on the unit circle scales up linearly scales a factor of $r$ as we move outwards from the origin and hence the unit polar basis vector at some radial distance is given as:

$$ \overline{\vec{e_{\theta}}} = \frac{ e_{\theta}}{r}$$

The overline stands for the vector being normalized

---

**References:**

[Pavel Grinfield's Tensor Analysis book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1461478669)